# How to catch click event on an editable DataTable cell?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, datatable, datatables

I use jQuery DataTable and I have an editable cell for entering scores. When use double click this field the cell is editable and I want to catch this event so that making the cell text selected as shown below:

```
$("td form input").focus(function () {
    concole.log('catched...');
});
```

or like that:

```
$('#dtbGrade td form').focus(function () {
    concole.log('catched...');
});
```

But I cannot catch the event when user double clicked the cell and the cell is focused. On the other hand the rendered html of the cell is as shown below (unnecessary lines was removed for brevity):

```
<table id="dtbGrade" role="grid" aria-describedby="dtbGrade_info">      
    <td>
        <form>
            <input autocomplete="off" name="value">
        </form>
    </td>       
</table>
```

Any idea to catch the dbclick event of this editable table cell?

Comment: https://api.jquery.com/dblclick/

Comment: Thanks but I had already tried this but had not worked :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have tried all of the suggetions above but anyhow none of them has not been worked. The worked code as shown below. If there is an edit needed comments are welcome... Thanks a lot Syden and Cris.

```
$('#dtbGrade').dblclick(function () {
    console.log("catched");
    $('#dtbGrade td form input').select();
});
```

Comment: Do bear in mind, that this is going to catch any double click inside the table, regardless of which cell / row / column you double clicked. If that is not a concern for you, then this is going to work just fine.

Comment: You are right, but what do you suggest? None of the other suggestions has worked. any idea?

Comment: Any idea about this?

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/bf7bfLur/
Gonna need more info, because it's working for me, as you wrote.

Comment: I need a solution by fixing your answer. It seems to be better than the working code. Any fix please?

Comment: My answer had a typo - check now. If that doesn't work, then I need more code in order to help you, because the code that you provided, is working fine for me.

Answer (score 0):

If the elements are added dynamically, this won't work. Perhaps try it like this:

```
$('#dtbGrade').on('dblclick', 'td form input', function() {
    console.log('caught')
});
```

This binds the event to dynamically added elements too.

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT 1**

@ClintEastwood  I couldn't help my self.

So this is in the same spirit as what you have below but this a bit more robust and flexible if you happen to want more rows in that table later on.

```js
// Provide function scope so we don't pollute the global namespace.
(function($) {
  // Function to handle our double click event.
  var _onRowDblClick = function(evt) {
    // "this" is the table row element we double clicked.
    $(this).find("form input").focus();

    // Stop this from bubbling out.
    evt.stopPropagation();
  }

  // Using jQuery delegate events we have one event for the whole table but 
  // it is still scoped to each row.  Now we can have more than one row and 
  // this will automatically hook to "tr" elements event if they are added 
  // dynamically after initial load.
  $("#dtbGrade").on("dblclick", "tr", _onRowDblClick);
})(window.jQuery);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="dtbGrade" role="grid" aria-describedby="dtbGrade_info">
  <tr>
    <td>
      <form>
        <input autocomplete="off" name="value">
      </form>
    </td>
    <td>Wanted and Extra Cell to better show example</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <form>
        <input autocomplete="off" name="otherValue">
      </form>
    </td>
    <td>We can more than on row now!!!</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Also the HTML you had in the original question wasn't valid HTML.  You needed a  "" element wrapping the table cells.

**Original**

Original answer below but misunderstood question see new recommendation above.

<s>Try this:</s>

```
$("table#dtbGrade").on("dblclick", "tr", function(evt) {
   // Do double click stuff
});

$("table#dtbGrade").on("focus", "tr td input", function(evt) {
  // DO NOT return false, preventDefault, ..etc.  You need the event to bubble out
  // or the dblClick event will not fire

  // Do Focus stuff.
});
```

I just played around with this on JS Fiddle and it worked fine.  What you might be doing is "evt.preventDefault()", "evt.stopPropagation", or "return false" from the focus handler which would prevent the double click handler from ever firing because it would never see the "clicks" on the input element.  This is one of those rare times where you need the click event to bubble out at least to the table row.

Comment: Thanks but not a better method than the answer.

Comment: No worries.  I think I misunderstood the question. (=

Comment: But if you have a better suggestion for this issue, of course you are welcome :)

Comment: @ClintEastwood  I couldn't help my self.  See updated answer above.